# Using mixpanel(in angular) with nginx [error]: Bad content type. Please use multipart

Tags: angular, nginx, multipartform-data, mixpanel, 400-bad-request

In the 'Response section' of Network Tab it shows text like
"**Bad content type.  Please use multipart.**"

I tried multiple approaches to get rid of the content-type issue

- Content-Type "multipart/form-data"
- Content-Type "multipart/related"
- Content-Type "application/json"
- Removing the content type Parameter

None of the solution works out!

## OVERVIEW

I am trying to use **mixpanel** in my angular application, but the network requests are getting blocked when trying to run the application on Brave or on Chrome with some **add blockers**.

[Screenshot : error without using nginx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwIx1.png)

```
POST https://api-js.mixpanel.com/track/?verbose=1&ip=1&_=1706583867562 504 (Gateway Timeout)
Mixpanel error: Bad HTTP status: 504 Gateway Timeout
Mixpanel error: [batch] Error; retry in 10000 ms
```

To get rid of the blocked Request I implemented the nginx config which is mentioned in the mixpanel documentation [mixpanel-official-doc](https://docs.mixpanel.com/docs/tracking-methods/sdks/javascript#tracking-via-proxy).

## This is my nginx.config file.

```
events {}
http {
    server {
        listen 4999 default backlog=16384;
        listen [::]:4999 default backlog=16384;

        location /lib.min.js {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $http_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            proxy_pass https://cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js;
        }

        location /lib.js {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $http_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            proxy_pass https://cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.js;
        }

        location /decide {
            proxy_set_header Host decide.mixpanel.com;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $http_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            proxy_pass https://decide.mixpanel.com/decide;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host api.mixpanel.com;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $http_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            proxy_pass https://api.mixpanel.com/;
        }
    }
}
```

## My app.component.Ts Code:

```
myid = "ae02abe786309xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
MIXPANEL_CUSTOM_LIB_URL = "http://localhost:4999/lib.min.js";
  
mixpanel.init(this.myid, {
   api_host: this.MIXPANEL_CUSTOM_LIB_URL,
   debug: true,
   track_pageview: true,
});
```

still got the same errors for blocking network requests along with CORS error.

[Screenshot: console log errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXIzO.png)

[Screenshot: Network Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZcSp.png)

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:4999/lib.min.js/track/?verbose=1&ip=1&_=1706584713221' from origin 'http://localhost:4222' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

**To get rid of the CORS error and to pass proxy
I looked for multiple solution on the web and end up with this nginx.config file.**

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    server {
        listen 4999 default backlog=16384;
        listen [::]:4999 default backlog=16384;
        location / {

             if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://localhost:4222' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain' always;
                return 204;
            }


            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://localhost:4222' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
            proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
            proxy_set_header Accept-Language $http_accept_language;
            proxy_set_header Host api.mixpanel.com;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $http_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            proxy_pass https://api.mixpanel.com/;
            proxy_set_header Content-Type "multipart/form-data";
        }
        
        location /api-js.mixpanel.com {

             if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://localhost:4222' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain' always;
                return 204;
            }

            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://localhost:4222' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
            proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
            proxy_set_header Accept-Language $http_accept_language;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $http_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            proxy_pass https://cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js;
            proxy_set_header Content-Type "multipart/form-data";
        }
        location /lib.min.js {

             if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://localhost:4222' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain' always;
                return 204;
            }

            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://localhost:4222' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
            proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
            proxy_set_header Accept-Language $http_accept_language;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $http_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            proxy_pass https://cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js;
            proxy_set_header Content-Type "multipart/form-data";
        }

        location /lib.js {

             if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://localhost:4222' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain' always;
                return 204;
            }

            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://localhost:4222' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
            proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
            proxy_set_header Accept-Language $http_accept_language;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $http_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            proxy_pass https://cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.js;
            proxy_set_header Content-Type "multipart/form-data";
        }

        location /decide {

             if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://localhost:4222' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain' always;
                return 204;
            }

            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://localhost:4222' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
            proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
            proxy_set_header Accept-Language $http_accept_language;
            proxy_set_header Host decide.mixpanel.com;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $http_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            proxy_pass https://decide.mixpanel.com/decide;
            proxy_set_header Content-Type "multipart/form-data";

        }
    }
}
```

## Now the console shows the following errors

```
mixpanel.service.ts:14 POST http://localhost:4999/lib.min.js/track/?verbose=1&ip=1&_=1706585271250 400 (Bad Request)
Mixpanel error: Bad HTTP status: 400 Bad Request
```

now in the Response section of Network Tab it shows text like
"**Bad content type.  Please use multipart.**"

I tried multiple approaches to get rid of the content-type issue

- Content-Type "multipart/form-data"
- Content-Type "multipart/related"
- Content-Type "application/json"
- Removing the content type Parameter

None of the solution works out
What was i am doing wrong ?